# using JDBC in servlets

Tags: mysql, tomcat, servlets

i am really new to the servlet concepts. just googled out some theories, studied and now i want a practical experience. all i want to do is to create a servlet that can access a mysql database. a simple JSP page that accepts a 'name' and 'marks' and then hit the servlet which in-turn access the database and enters the name and marks into the database.

i Have created a database and a JSP page. i have created a servlet too. i have the mysql connector in my library and i am referring to it with Class.forname() concept. but when i run this on my server (Tomcat v6.0) it gives a class not found exception for 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. But when i run this mysql part in another project which is not a servlet (its just a simple java project) it executes properly and the database is also updated.

the problem is only when i use that piece of code on the server with a servlet. i tried googling and it said i have to include the mysql connector in the WEB-INF/lib of the tomcat. But i could not find this path at all. any advice regarding this would prove helpful to me. thanks in advance. :) this is my mysql part of the code,
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

```
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String name = request.getParameter("name");

    int marks = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("marks"));

    try {
        System.out.println("0");
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/testdb123","root","root");

        String qr= "INSERT INTO stuinfo " +
                   "VALUES ('"+name+"',10)";
        System.out.println(qr);

        System.out.println("1");
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        System.out.println("2");
        stmt.executeUpdate(qr);
        System.out.println("3");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Servlet containers like Tomcat run WAR (Web ARchive) files or folders. The standard folder structure of a WAR is:

```
(ROOT)
|
+- (content files and folders)
|
+- META-INF (optional)
|  |
|  +- MANIFEST.MF (standard Java manifest file, optional)
|  |
|  +- (other files and folders, optional)
|
+- WEB-INF (Tomcat considers it optional for ease of use)
   |
   +- web.xml (the deployment descriptor)
   |
   +- classes (folder that contains all the classes for this web application)
   |
   +- lib (contains all library JARs for this application THIS IS WHAT YOU WANT)
   |
   +- (other files and folders, optional)
```

Stuff in `WEB-INF/classes` and JARs in `WEB-INF/lib` are automatically included in the classpath of your application.

In your application folder, you should create a `WEB-INF` folder, inside it a `lib` folder and place the `mysql-connector-XXX.jar` in there. This will solve your *classpath* problems. The servlet container does not automatically create the folder structure.

ALTERNATIVELY, you can copy the `mysql-connector-XXX.jar` driver to the `lib` folder of Tomcat. This will make it available to all applications.

---

Having said that, please consider the following as well:

1. Always close connections in a finally block:

   ```
   Connection conn = null;
   try {
       ...
       conn = // get it somehow
   }
   catch( /* any exception you can handle, throw or let go of the rest */ ) {
       ...
   }
   finally {
       // close other JDBC resources (e.g. Statements, ResultSets etc) in a similar way
       if( conn != null ) {
           try { conn.close(); }
           catch(Exception(ignore) {}
       }
   }
   ```
2. Using `DriverManager.getConnection` all the time will hurt performance in real life. After you feel confident with yourself about the basics, take a look at connection pooling and the `javax.sql.DataSource`. *Later, not now!*

Comment: thanks a lot Nikos!!!!! it worked!!! you told that once i feel confident about these stuff i have to take a look at javax.sql.DataSource for some efficient method to access a database. may i please know what all should i know to make myself ready to take the next step??

As of now, i have a simple jsp page with two fields - name and marks. From here when user enters data, i am hitting a servlet that enters these details into the DB. now i am trying out different constraints on the table structure like primary key, etc. will really find it helpful if i am lucky to get some guidance from you.

Comment: You should follow [this example](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html). Then instead of using `DriverManager.getConnection`, use the code from [this](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/UsingDataSources) (the `InitialContext` stuff). In short the `DataSource` is a connection pool. Because obtaining connections with the DB is slow, this obtains a number of connections upfront and uses them, saving the time to reconnect.

Comment: "In your application folder, you should create a WEB-INF folder, inside it a lib folder and place the mysql-connector-XXX.jar in there. This will solove your classpath problems. The servlet container does not automatically create the folder structure."- nikos, this method is not working, actually m not able add that mysql connector to a folder in my project why is that??